# how to retrieve a single row data from cursor android?

Tags: android

I want to retrieve the data from cursor when pressing the button. For the first time I want to show first row data, after pressing button I need to show second row data. How can I achieve this? I have more number of rows in my database.

While I am using following code I am getting last row data.

```
for(int i=0;i<cursor.getColumnCount();i++){
    String path=c.getString(2);
    Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
    title.setText(c.getString(1));
    brewerimage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Comment: You mean title.setText(c.getString(1));  this returns your last row right?

Comment: Actually what i need is how to get particular row data from cursor.

Comment: @Amsheer, that will be the order of the column, not the row. Each time cursor will fetch a row, in that, we can get the values of Column fields using this order.

Comment: @vinodkumar shall i see your select query.

Comment: i am getting all the the table data from data base to cursor

Comment: Cursor cs=sd.query(Tname,null,null, null, null, null, null, null);

Comment: So you are saying there is only one query like (select * from..) and whenever you press the button you need the count increased 0, 1, 2, 3 etc. right?

Comment: yes   i want to show row by row data @Amsheer

Answer (score 2):

For the first timebutton click, 
cursor.moveToFirst();

Then keep on using,
cursor.moveToNext()

until end of the row.

To be more specific:

```
 if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
                            String path=c.getString(2);
                            Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
                            title.setText(c.getString(1));
                            brewerimage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                        } while(cursor.moveToNext();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to move your cursor to first row. Please try this:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst())
{
    do
        {
         String path=cursor.getString(2);
         Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
         title.setText(cursor.getString(1));
         brewerimage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Comment: i want to get particular row data

Comment: what kind of criteria you need to get that particular row? an id? a specific path?

Answer (score 1):

You can take first row of data like this
Replace 0 in 
    cursor.getString(0);
with your value;

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst())
{
    do
        {
         String path=cursor.getString(0);
         title.setText(path);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this hope it will help you:

```
try {
 if (cursorOne.moveToFirst()) { 

                    String path=c.getString(2);
                    Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
                    title.setText(c.getString(1));
                    brewerimage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                //no need to look up column index since you already know it due to the projection used
  }
} finally {
 cursorOne.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

                    for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {    

                        String path=c.getString(2);
                        Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
                        title.setText(c.getString(1));
                        brewerimage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    }

            }
```

Comment: Good idea of using `Cursor` methods in a `for loop`

Answer (score 1):

After read your comments i have one idea. That is leave the query as like now.

**Step 1**

Save your data in static ArrayList or POJO class

**Step 2:**

Whenever you want to click button just increase the cont +1 and save it. Use this count as position and easily get values.

Comment: its working but i want to change image bitmap when ever click on button

Comment: same as other fields save the image path. Once the button click then fetch the path and convert as bitmap. After that do whatever you want with that image.

Comment: You have any doubts or any issues pls ask

Answer (score 0):

You can get particular at the given position as like.

```
 public void getRowAt(int posAt){

        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from "+tableName+" LIMIT 1 OFFSET "+posAt, null);

        int count = cursor.getCount();

        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            // here your can get your row data.
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using database so you getting record from database am i right ?
so you getting record in cursor so from which column you getting data you have to pass that column name in  your cursor so you are getting result .
example :

```
if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

            cursor.moveToFirst();
            do {
                myDatarecordModel = new DataRecordModel();
                myDatarecordModel.setStrDataRecordingID(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(AppStackFields.DATARECORDING_ID)));

 } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
```